# Using $this in "anonymous" object

Tags: php, anonymous-class

I am using the following class to mimic anonymous objects in PHP:

```
class AnonymousObject
{
    protected $methods = array();

    public function __construct(array $options) {
        $this->methods = $options;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $callable = null;
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->methods))
            $callable = $this->methods[$name];
        elseif(isset($this->$name))
            $callable = $this->$name;

        if (!is_callable($callable))
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Method {$name} does not exist");

        return call_user_func_array($callable, $arguments);
    }
}
```

(https://gist.github.com/Mihailoff/3700483)

Now, as long as the declared functions stand on their own everything works fine, but whenever I try to call one function from the other like this ...

```
$anonymous = new AnonymousObject(array(
    "foo" => function() { $this->bar(); }, 
    "bar" => function() { } 
));
```

then of course I get `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

Is there any way to work around this problem?

Comment: Upgrade to PHP7 and you'll get real anonymous classes :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the bind() or [bindTo() method](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) of the Closure instance that represents the anonymous function.

```
<?php
class AnonymousObject
{
    protected $methods = array();

    public function __construct(array $options) {
        $this->methods = $options;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $callable = null;
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->methods))
            $callable = $this->methods[$name];
        elseif(isset($this->$name))
            $callable = $this->$name;

        if (!is_callable($callable))
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Method {$name} does not exists");

        $callable = $callable->bindTo($this);
        return call_user_func_array($callable, $arguments);
    }
}

$anonymous = new AnonymousObject(array(
    "foo" => function() { echo 'foo'; $this->bar(); }, 
    "bar" => function() { echo 'bar'; } 
));

$anonymous->foo();
```

(example not quite right, since it will work only with anonymous functions; not with all the other callable() alternatives like e.g. the $this->name part)

prints `foobar`.

Comment: Would there be any benefit in looping the options in the constructor and binding at that point rather than in the __call() ?

Comment: Probably yes. I chose the safe way since the function reference might be available outside the class defintion and from there bound to another object.

Comment: @VolkerK you can't rebind an instance. Every time you call ->bindTo() or ::bind() it returns a new instance. So there should be no worries about external side effects.